# Display structured data in component passed from controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, json, lightning-design-system

I have a need to display a chatter feed in a custom page using lightning components. I am able to get the chatter feed body in the client side controller in the proper format (as per the console log) but its not structured and displays in a single line when passed it to the the component.

I understand it might be because it is being passed as a String attribute, but is there any other way ?

---

## Component

```
<aura:component  access="global" controller ="ChatterFeedController">
<aura:attribute name = "groupattid" type="String" /> 
<aura:attribute name = "groupatt" type="String[]" />
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.userFeedItem}" value="{!this}"/>

<div class="slds-post__content slds-text-longform">             
  <p><b> <ui:outputRichText aura:id="outputRT" value="{!feed.body.text}"/>
  </p> <br/> 
</div>
</aura:component>
```

---

## Controller

```
  userFeedItem: function(component, event, helper) {
     var userFeed = component.get("c.getFeedData");
     var groupID = component.get("v.groupattid");
     userFeed.setParams({"groupId" : groupID});
     userFeed.setCallback(this,function(response){
     var state = response.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
           var jtext     = response.getReturnValue();
           var FeedAtt   = component.get("v.groupatt");
    for (var i=0; i<jtext.elements.length; ++i){ 
      FeedAtt.push(jtext.elements[i]);
      component.set("v.groupatt",FeedAtt);
    }

      } else {
            console.log('Problem getting feed, response state: ' + state);
        }    
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(userFeed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple way.. Add "white-space: pre-wrap;" in the css.